# 401 when my Oauth2 Client call my Oauth2 Resource Server

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to understand how works the new Autorization Server form spring.
So I created 3 apps :

1. an auth-server using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server and running on 9090 port
2. a resource server using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server and running on 8081
3. a client using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client running on 8080

When I start the apps and login with my user I can load the index.html page but when I launch the url who try to call the resource server I got a 401.

Here my SecurityConfig class from auth server :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    //An instance of RegisteredClientRepository for managing clients.
    @Bean
    RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        var clientId = "XXX";

        RegisteredClient clientThymeleaf = RegisteredClient
                .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret("YYY")
                .clientAuthenticationMethods(clientAuthenticationMethods -> clientAuthenticationMethods.addAll(Set.of(
                        ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC
                )))
                .authorizationGrantTypes(grandTypes -> grandTypes.addAll(Set.of(
                    AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
                    AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN
                )))
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/spring")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
                .scopes(scopes -> scopes.addAll(Set.of(
                    "product.read",
                    OidcScopes.OPENID
                )))
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();


        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(clientThymeleaf);
    }    
}
```

Here my YAML config from ressource-server :

```
spring :
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

Here my Controller Class from ressource-server :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/produits")
public class ProduitController {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProduitController.class);


    @Autowired
    private ProduitService produitService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Produit>> listerProduits(Principal principal) {
        log.info("\n** User {} try to get all product.\n", principal.getName());
        List<Produit> produits = produitService.listerProduits();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(produits);
    }
}
```

Here my Service Class from ressource-server :

```
@Service
public class ProduitService {

    @Autowired
    private ProduitRepository produitRepository;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_product.read')")
    public List<Produit> listerProduits() {
        return produitRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here my YAML config from client side :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9090
        registration:
          spring:
            provider: spring
            client-id: XXX
            client-secret: YYY
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: product.read, openid
```

Here my Controller from Client side :

```
@Controller
public class ProduitController {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProduitController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProduitService produitService;
    @GetMapping("/produits")
    public String listerProduits(Model model) {
        log.info("\n** Show Page List Products\n");

        Mono<List<Produit>> produits = produitService.getProduits();

//        log.info("\n** Lists de {} produits obtenus\n", produits.size());
        log.info("\n** Lists de produits obtenus\n");
        model.addAttribute("produits", produits);
        return "listeProduits";
    }

}
```

Here my Service from Client side :

```
@Service
public class ProduitService {

    @Value("${ressource-uri.products}")
    private String ressource_products_uri;
    private WebClient webClient;


    public ProduitService(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Mono<List<Produit>> getProduits() {

        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(ressource_products_uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Produit>>() {
                });

    }

}
```

Here my WebClient configuration from client side :

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        // @formatter:off
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        // @formatter:off
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .authorizationCode()
//                        .refreshToken()
//                        .clientCredentials()
//                        .password()
                        .build();
        // @formatter:on
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

}
```

I know I miss some configuration to automatically get the access token and add it on the request from client to resource server.

I don't want to use Gateway! I want o use WebClient!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your resource server conf: `issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000` when it should probably be `issuer-uri: http://localhost:9090`. Could you add your logs with DEBUG level?

Comment: I don't see the typo you're talking about. What you suggest is the same as what I put as config

Comment: Look twice. Search for `9000` in this page. I believe it should be replaced with `9090`

Comment: Wow Thank you very much! my code was good and I didn't see the typo. Thank you again!